# Shifting Elements to the Right After a Certain Index

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, element

I have an array `_data` and I'm trying to add a number to the array at a certain `position`. Every number after the index of `position` should be shifted one index to the right. I'm having trouble conceptually in doing this.

This is what I have as of now:

```
void list::add(int num, size_t position)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
  {
     _data[position + i + 1] = _data[position + i];
  }
_data[position] = num; 
}
```

For example, say num = 9 and position = 3 and the given values in the array are `{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`. I would want it to be `{1, 3, 4, 9, 5, 6, 7}`. What ends up happening, though, is that it grabs the number that has already been replaced and puts that back into the array. (ex `1, 3, 4, 9, 5, 5, 5`}.

Comment: Shift the righteous first

Comment: Use a small array, say with only two elements. Take a piece of paper. Using a pencil draw two squares, and put "1" and "2" inside each square. That's your array with two values. Now, go through your code, one line at a time, and update each value in the array, on paper, exactly how your code does it. You should be able to easily figure out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's depending on type of your variable `_data`:

If it's an array:

```
for (std::size_t i = _size - 1; i != position; --i)
{
   _data[i] = _data[i - 1];
}
_data[position] = num;
```

If it's a vector:

```
_data.insert(_data.begin() + position, num);
```

Anyway, it's recommended to use a `std::vector` instead of raw array, and it's NOT recommended to use underscore at the beginning of variable name